# How to remove a sprite when it reaches a certain point or it is touched?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to make a game in cocos2d wherein I have sprites dropping from the top of the screen. Now, once the sprite is tapped, it should move back up. This works for me just fine but, there are some instances wherein the sprite would go back down after it goes off the screen. Also, my sprites don't disappear once they reach a certain y-axis position on the screen. Here's part of my code

```
-(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint loc = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:[touch locationInView:[touch view]]];

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(sprite.position.x - (sprite.contentSize.width/2), sprite.position.y - (sprite.contentSize.height/2), sprite.contentSize.width, sprite.contentSize.height);

if(CGRectContainsPoint(rect, loc))
{
    [sprite runAction:[CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteCaught)]];
}}

-(void)spriteCaught
{
//currentPos is an integer to get the current position of the sprite
id moveUp = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(currentPos, 500)];
[sprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:moveUp, nil]];
if(sprite.position.y >= 480)
{
    [self removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];
}}
```

Also, I'm not sure if my syntax is correct but my conditional statement (The one that checks the position in the y-axis of the sprite) doesn't work either. How do I go about fixing this? Any help and suggestion is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manual rect, use sprite's bounding box.

```
         if(CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox], loc))
```

Also update spriteCaught function.

```
-(void)spriteCaught
{
    CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    float dest_y = s.height+sprite.contentSize.height*0.5f; //assumed ur sprite's anchor y = 0.5

    //currentPos is an integer to get the current position of the sprite
    id moveUp = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(sprite.position, dest_y)];
    id calBlokc = [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node)
    {
        //here node = sprite tht runs this action
        [node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
    }];
    id sequence = [CCSequence actions:moveUp, calBlokc, nil];

    [sprite runAction:sequence];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I just adjusted the value of dest_y to s.height + s.contentSize.height / 2; and it works now. This the only problem left for my game. Well almost, I still have the pause scenario left. Many thanks!

Comment: I have another question. How do I delay the dropping of sprites? Like at first like maybe 20 seconds, only one sprite would fall at a time, then more would start falling after that. How can I do that?

Comment: dont know how you are generating dropping sprite, if it is in separate schedular then you can change schedular duration by unScheduling and re scheduling again...better post it in seperate question with code snippet...thanks

Comment: s.height + s.contentSize.height / 2; is not required...just reduce move up duration...from 1 to 0.3 like that....